# Visual Studio Xamarin Forms not showing Design View

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I am using visual studio 2019 community v16.8.6 and xaml design view shows me only this banner of hot reload.
I have double checked to see if hot reload and xaml designer is enabled.

Any idea why I cannot see my xaml rendered in design view? Any help is appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a known limitation.
[image]